# Wordpress cash on delivery missing for specific address

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with COD in woocommerce.
For this address, the COD is disabled:
https://ibb.co/GMHCW9c

If I changed address2, work very well.

Here are the settings for the module:
https://ibb.co/vwwmWCg

I don't have any restrictions for postal codes. I think it's a problem with postal codes, but I don't find this. I want keep cash on delivery everywhere.

Thank you!!